# how to upload ppt and display ppt in website using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I display an uploaded power point presentation inside a c# asp.net web application?

Answer (score 1):

quick answer, use a control. Try the big names like aspose, telerik, etc. Also look at www.slideshare.com as they might have a control you can embed on your page.

Basically you will need a control to do it or learn OpenXML and parse the ppt file yourself.

try http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=2898 which is aspose. You can convert ppt to FLV movie then just use a FLV player which are abundant on the internet.